# How to await an asynchonous method defined inside subscribe before to complete an Rxjs Observable?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

Let's take the code bellow:

```
myObservable.subscribe({
  next: async () => {
    await something();
  },
  complete: () => {
    console.log('All async task are comlpeted');
  }
});
```

The problem is that the `console.log` is called after the last `next` is triggered but I want it to be called after the last `something()` is finished.

Is there any way to do that ?

I specify that I implemented the `myObservable` by myself using `new Obsercable(observer => ...)`. So  it could be modified.

Comment: If your `next` function always returns a `Promise`, can you `await` it (or `.then`) inside your `new Observable` construct? If you're already calling `.next(value)` then you have the control to decide when to call `.complete()`.

Comment: Not possible, this is the typedef of an observer:
```export interface Observer<T> {
    closed?: boolean;
    next: (value: T) => void;
    error: (err: any) => void;
    complete: () => void;
}```. It returns `void` :-(.

Comment: Yes you're right. I've just tested it to see and it makes sense why this is the case.

Comment: I don't know rxjs very well so I don't know what would be an idiomatic approach, but here's an example of achieving something like you want by passing in a resolver to the `next` function that can be used to then trigger the `complete`: https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-monad-tt618

Comment: @jamie-dixon It's interessant but this example works well because there is only one message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would either a) stick to the observable recipe, and convert promises to observables, or b) stick to the promise/async-await pattern, and convert observables to promises. I frankly have no idea how to successfully *mix* those two.

Rx-based solution:

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

myObservable.pipe(
    switchMap(() => from(something()),
    finalize(() => console.log('All async task are comlpeted')),
).subscribe(someFunction);
```

Comment: You should use `mergeMap` instead of `switchMap` to get the same behaviour as in the code from the question. You also don't have to use `from` as `mergeMap` and `switchMap` accept Promises directly.

Comment: @fridoo Interesting, I had no idea that `switchMap` (and siblings) also accepted promises. Good to know.